# Authentication on Neo4j with Python

Tags: python, neo4j

When trying to run my application (using neo4jrb 2.2.5) I got this error.
in a browser localhost:7474/db/data returns json:

```
 "message": "No authorization header supplied.",
    "code": "Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed"
```

this is my Python code for access:

```
graph_db = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
```

Comment: go to http://localhost:7474/db/data/ using your navigator, you should get a response

Comment: I get this error
Neo.ClientError.Security.AuthorizationFailed

Comment: Authentication is turned on by default in the latest releases so you have to provide authentication token or turn it off by updating the config file: http://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-2-milestone-1-release/

Comment: if you get an Authorization error, you are pointing on your database, so your problem is resolved (to add authorization header support, check py2neo's documentation, removing it is a bad idea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide authorization information thru neo4jrb.

Since version 2.2 Neo4j supports authorization.
http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-security.html

Default values are

```
user: neo4j
pass: neo4j
```

you can turn off authorization in configuration file neo4j-server.properties

```
# Disable authorization
dbms.security.auth_enabled=false
```